# svnadmin: Expected current rev to be 51 but found 52

Tags: svn, recovery

I just had to recover from a backup and surprisingly am having issues with an svn repository after it.
Every operation on this repository fails, I can't checkout, export, not even recover.
The output of "svnadmin recover is": svnadmin: Expected current rev to be 51 but found 52

The code is safe as there are working copies, but how can I get this repository usable again?

Comment: Can you `svnadmin dump`?

Comment: yes, it dumps all but the last revision. I guess that helps, thanks!

Comment: how do you do your backups?  sounds like there could be an issue where a revision is only half backed up?

Comment: Yes, I wonder myself about this. It happened on a vServer hosted by a professional provider. The restore was done from one of the automatic backups done daily, few hours old.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read from the [SVN documentation about the FS_FS backend.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends.fsfs) But basically, the file called "db/current" in your repo is a text file with the latest revision number, whereas db/revs/ is a folder containing a file for every revision (which after 1.5, might be split in shard folders).

If your backup tool decends into revs/ and backs up all files there AND a user does a commit while you're backing up, it's possible that you'll miss that latest commit before the rev file is moved from db/transactions/ to db/revs/ BUT still backup a db/current file that's been incremented. That is, you have revs/ for 51 revisions but current lists "52" as the most recent commit!

The recommended way to ensure a consistent backup is to ignore db/transactions (since that's scratch space to be used while building a rev) and backup db/current BEFORE you backup db/revs. Worst case here is revs/ might contain, for example, 52 revisions and current points to 51. That's consistent and everything will work fine. "svnadmin recovery" will even fix this for you.

HOWEVER, if you don't backup db/current first (as you didn't) it's very simple to open it with vim, nano, or another text editor and simply decrement the number. In your case, change 52 to 51 and everything should verify correctly.

The part about backups is also documented in a document [comparing FS_FS to FS_Base that I found](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/fsfs) from when FS_FS was first introduced